# Authentication mode=“Forms” causing redirect in WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, cassini, iis-express

I have a WCF end point inside my .NET 4.0 Web Application project. Using the VS2010 WCF Test Client, I can connect to the service correctly. However when I go to use the service I get a generic error message:

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

When I looked at the requests on IIS Express I got the following:

> Request started: POST http://machinename:port/Services/Services.svc
>
> Request started: GET http://machinename:port/Services/Services.svc?AspxAutoDectectCookieSupport=1
>
> Request started: GET http://machinename:port/(X(1)A(LKwosYYszAEkAAAAMDE2YzlmNWItNTZIOS00ZDY1LTgzOTAtNDIxNDgyOWZIYWViJ86TX46muUQoL_psmkZK2rgWbO41))/Services/Services.svc?AspxAutoDectectCookieSupport=1
>
> Request ended: "http://machinename:port/Services/Services.svc" with HTTP status 302.0
>
> Request ended: "http://machinename:port/Services/Services.svc?AspxAutoDectectCookieSupport=1" with HTTP status 302.0
>
> Request ended: "http://machinename:port/Services/Services.svc?AspxAutoDectectCookieSupport=1" with HTTP status 200.0

So it seems like after POSTing to the service it is getting redirected to the standard web page for the service. Yet when I remove:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms cookieless="AutoDetect" loginUrl="~/Security/LoginClient.aspx" name="FORMAUTH" />
```

from the web.config it works.  Any ideas what is happening? I have tried to remove the folder the service is in from authentication (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593720/authentication-mode-forms-causing-errors-in-wcf-end-point) but the issue still remains.

While this works using the Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini) when I run it through IIS Express 7.5 the same error occurs with or without authentication.

Comment: Hello ! Facing the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide authorization for your web services to be contacted anonymously in your web.config:

```
<location path="MyWebServices">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This assumes that you keep all of your services in a folder called `MyWebServices` relative to the root of the application. You have to allow `*` or it will force a login for access.

Comment: This is what I thought it was, which was why I asked it here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593720/authentication-mode-forms-causing-errors-in-wcf-end-point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593720/authentication-mode-forms-causing-errors-in-wcf-end-point) but having tried that it still redirects me

Comment: Not working. If any issues is thrown in the WCF, it still redirects to the default loginUrl. I don't think the problem is about authorizing some users to the WCF, but about "How to not redirect to the default login page when an exception or something is thrown"

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue as soon as I use the machinename instead of localhost in the service address. I did try to use a "baseAddressPrefixFilters" but without success.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://XLSiteSampleD.aginsurance.intranet/PIXLSiteSample" />
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

I thought that  option could have been  to enable the aspNetCompatibility in the web.config 
    
with the related attribute on the service :
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
                                 AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
But is does not the trick either :(

It only works with an address like http://localhost/VirtualSite/MyService.svc without a domain and without the baseAddressPrefixFilters !

V.